# Pass data between ListFragment and GoogleMapsFragment

Tags: android, maps, fragment

**INTRODUCTION**

I've readed some questions/answers about how to pass data between fragments, but I'm a bit new with this and I stil have some things unclear.

In my app, lets say that after doing some things, I have a dual pane view (tablet) where at the left side I've got a ListFragment and at the right side a GoogleMapsFragment.

**FUNCTIONALITY**

When I click on one list's element (a direction), GoogleMapsFragment should focus that place. I achieve to do this individually, I mean, on a single pane view (smartphone).

But to do this in a tablet, i don't know how to do it.

**WHAT TO GET**

What I need to get is when I click on a list's element, this element must pass the direction values to GoogleMapsFragment to focus on it, but I'm not able to get these values from GoogleMapsFragment.

Answer (score 0):

You always can use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to pass some data between different app components.
It will make your developers life much easier.